# Is there a way to show 24 hour time format in Skype 8?

Tags: skype, time

After upgrading Skype 7.x to 8.x, the timestamps of messages are shown in the "American" format (like "8:55 PM") instead of 24 hour format ("20:55"). I have Windows 7 and all other software uses the system setting of 24 hour format.

Is there a way to adjust that?

The similar older questions ([Change the date time format in Skype chat](https://superuser.com/questions/379739) and [How to change time format in Skype](https://superuser.com/questions/439554)) are about older Skype versions that apparently behave differently and those solutions do not work with Skype 8.

Comment: I would extend a question to dates, which also seem to be displayed American style (M/D/Y) and not according to current locale. I am on Linux Skype 8.26.0.70.

Comment: Skype 8 is missing some obvious features. It's surprising Microsoft released it as such, it feels like some alpha version.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't appear that it can, but it looks like it's been submitted to be added in the future. Check out the Microsoft Website [Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/forum/skype_win10-skype_startms-skype_installms/how-do-i-change-the-date-format-in-skype/9a5dc31d-b532-4d2a-b6a7-f863680d7507)

In a nutshell, Microsoft agreed that they see the value in it and will work on implementing it in the future.

Comment: Please try to include the key information from a linked page within your answer in case the linked page ever goes away.

Comment: It boggles the mind that a Microsoft product ignores the basic Windows settings...